# Manipulation of a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to model a intersection. Below is the code that I have written. Based on the time to the intersection, I have given preferences to each vehicle. To check collision I want the time difference between vehicles occupying the intersection to be 10 seconds. On running this code, it gives me "KeyError:1". Could somebody help ?

```
number_of_vehicles = 3
preference_dict = {'Vehicle1':1, 'Vehicle2': 3, 'Vehicle3':2}

time_to_intersection = {'Vehicle1':64, 'Vehicle2':72, 'Vehicle3': 69}

preference = 1
while preference < number_of_vehicles:

    for key1,key2 in preference_dict.items():
        if preference_dict[key1] == preference and preference_dict[key2] == preference+1:
            if time_to_intersection[key1] > time_to_intersection[key2]:
                time_to_intersection[key2]+=50*preference
            time_diff = time_to_intersection[key2] - time_to_intersection[key1]
            print "The time diff is:",time_diff
            if time_diff < 10:
                time_to_intersection[key2] +=50
    print time_to_intersection
    preference+=1
```

Comment: in `time_to_intersection[key2]` , key2 is either 1,3 or 2, and you try to use it as a key but they do only exist as value in preference_dict

Comment: That strikes me as a very strange way to model this state. Why not just use an array (a list) of tuples, if you're allergic to actual objects? E.g. `state = [(1, 64), (3, 72), (2, 69)]` or something. I'm not sure I understand the point of the "preference", but I kept the values you had.

Comment: The point of preference is that the vehicle that needs lowest time to reach the intersection is given the first preference

Answer (score 3):

`dict.items()` function returns a list of tuples. Each tuple is a `(key, value)` tuple. 
When you write:

```
for key1, key2 in preference_dict.items():
```

What actually written is:

```
for key1, key2 in [('Vehicle1', 1), ('Vehicle2', 3), ('Vehicle3', 2)]:
```

python's auto unpacking will put `tuple[0]` into `key1` and `tuple[1]` into `key2`.
Which means, in the very first iteration `key1 = 'Vehicle1'` and `key2 = 1`.
Right afterwards you write `preference_dict[key1]` which is 1... but `preference_dict[key2]` which is `preference_dict[1]` does not exist.

Comment: Its true. What should I do then, to iterate multiple keys in a loop, instead of dict.items() ?

Comment: You can always use `dict.keys()` which returns a list of the **keys** only. In order to iterate multiple keys you can do a nested for loop: `for key1 in dict.keys():  for key2 in dict.keys(): ...`. I can be more helpful if you'll clarify what you want to get :).

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError` typically occurs, when you ask a dictionary for a key, which does
not exists.

In your cae it is when you ask for `preference_dict[key2]`.

This is good example of how readibility of code counts. Using more explanatory
variable names will often help to detect such errors already during coding.

Below is reformatted code with modified names. It still contains the error, but
it shall illustrate, how the readability of code changes.

```
number_of_vehicles = 3
pref_dct = {'Vehicle1': 1, 'Vehicle2': 3, 'Vehicle3': 2}

time_to_intersection = {'Vehicle1': 64, 'Vehicle2': 72, 'Vehicle3': 69}

pref = 1
while pref < number_of_vehicles:

    for veh_name, veh_pref in pref_dct.items():
        if pref_dct[veh_name] == pref and pref_dct[veh_pref] == pref+1:
            if time_to_intersection[veh_name] > time_to_intersection[veh_pref]:
                time_to_intersection[veh_pref] += 50 * pref
            time_diff = (time_to_intersection[veh_pref] -
                        time_to_intersection[veh_name])
            print "The time diff is:", time_diff
            if time_diff < 10:
                time_to_intersection[veh_pref] += 50
    print time_to_intersection
    pref += 1
```